# Javascript forEach Loop

Tags: javascript, foreach

Trying to make this function true. I think the problem is in my for loop.

```
function forEach(array, callback){    
    console.log(array, callback);
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    }
}

 // testing your code with console.assert
var total = 1;
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
function multiplyTotal(a) {
    total *= a;
}
forEach(myArray, multiplyTotal);
// and finally assert; if this fails, the program stops
console.assert(total === 24);
```

Comment: You don't actually call you `callback`? What did you expect to see happen? Add `callback(array[i]);` in your `for` loop. Or just use the existing `forEach` functions in Javascript.

Comment: Your problem is the empty body of that for loop. You'll need to execute the things that you expect your function to do in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function forEach(array, callback){    
    console.log(array, callback);
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       callback(array[i]); // you need to call callback function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, Javascript already has a built in function for this:

```
myArray.forEach(multiplyTotal);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp